# How to invert mouse scroll wheel zoom direction in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, mouse-wheel

When scrolling down the mouse wheel with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>, the zoom decreases. I would like it to increase when I scroll down, and vice versa.

Is there a way to change it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open `about:config` and set the preference:

For Firefox 17+:

`mousewheel.with_control.delta_multiplier_y = -100` // default 100

For Firefox <=16:

`mousewheel.withcontrolkey.numlines = -1` // default 1